# htaccess index.php redirect to root

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

Okay so I have a few questions regarding htaccess.

First I would like `website/index.php` to be `website/` even if someone types in `index.php` at the end.

Secondly I would like to remove the `.php` even if you type it in and add a `/` at the end `website/about-us.php` to `website/about-us/`.

I added this to remove the extension at the end:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

except not 100% sure on how to add the `/`, and everything I have found to change the `index.php` to the root of the url isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule,

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^index.php$ www.{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```